# Recuperating pixel data from fragment shader results in unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, glsl, processing, shader, p5.js

I'm currently trying to use a fragment shader to transport some particle position data (and in the future, modify it). I have no problem sending the data to the shader using a sampler2D texture, but when I try to recuperate the data, My 20 particles suddenly have the wrong positions. I've printed as many outputs as possible and have minimized the code as much as I can yet still fail to understand where I'm wrong.

a reproducible minimized version is available on the p5js website [here](https://editor.p5js.org/itsKaspar/sketches/ei5YwYVK5)

Here is my sketch.js :

```
let theShader;
let shaderTexture;

let NUM_PARTICLES = 20;
let particleTexture;
let particles = [];

function preload(){
    theShader = loadShader('basic.vert', 'basic.frag');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400, WEBGL);
  
  // Initiate Particles
  for(let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES;i++){
    particles.push(createVector(i*20,i*20,0));
  }
  
  // Initialize Shader
  shaderTexture = createGraphics(NUM_PARTICLES, 1, WEBGL);
  shaderTexture.noStroke();
  
  // Create Particle Texture
  particleTexture = createImage(NUM_PARTICLES, 1);
  
  // Fill Particle Texture
  particleTexture.loadPixels();
  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {   
    particleTexture.pixels[i*4+0] = map(particles[i].x,0,width,0,255); // R
    particleTexture.pixels[i*4+1] = map(particles[i].y,0,height,0,255); // G
    particleTexture.pixels[i*4+2] = 0; // B
    particleTexture.pixels[i*4+3] = 255; // A
  }
  particleTexture.updatePixels();
}

function draw() {  
  translate(-width/2, -height/2);
  background(255);
  
  // Display Particles Before Modification
  for(let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES;i++){
    circle(particles[i].x,particles[i].y,10); // draw circle at particle location
  }

  // Apply Texture
  shaderTexture.shader(theShader); // set shader
  theShader.setUniform('text', particleTexture); // send particleTexture to shader
  shaderTexture.rect(0,0,NUM_PARTICLES,1); // set rect to recieve shader out
  
  // Print Shader Output
  for(let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES;i++){
    let newPos = shaderTexture.get(i, 0);
    print(newPos);
  }
  
  // Update and Display Particles
  for(let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES;i++){
    let newPos = shaderTexture.get(i, 0);
    particles[i].x = map(newPos[0],0,255,0,width);
    particles[i].y = map(newPos[1],0,255,0,height);
    fill(255,0,0);
    circle(particles[i].x,particles[i].y,10);
  }

  noLoop();
}
```

and here is my fragment shader which should not be modifying anything :

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D text;

void main() {
  vec2 particle = texture2D(text, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y)).xy;

  gl_FragColor = vec4(particle.x,particle.y,0.0,1.0); // R,G,B,A
}
```

also my vertex shader which is default :

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

attribute vec3 aPosition;

void main() {
  vec4 positionVec4 = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);

  positionVec4.xy = positionVec4.xy * 2.0 - 1.0; 

  gl_Position = positionVec4;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looking up a texture with [`texture2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/texture.xhtml) the texture coordinates must be specified in range [0.0, 1.0]. (0, 0) is the bottom left and (1, 1) is the top right. However [`gl_FragCoord.xy`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) contains window coordinates, with top left (0.5, 0.5) and top right (width-0.5, height-0.5).
Hence you need to divide `gl_FragCoord` by the size of the viewport. Since you draw on a rectangle with the size *NUM_PARTICLESx1* (width == NUM_PARTICLES, height = 1), you must divide `gl_FragCoord.x` by *NUM_PARTICLES*:

<s>`vec2 particle = texture2D(text, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y)).xy;`</s>

```c
vec2 particle = texture2D(text, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x/20.0, 0.0)).xy;
```

---

Alternatively you can add a `size` uniform to the fragment shader and divide `gl_FragCoord.xy` by `size`:

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec2 size;

void main() {
  
  vec2 particle = texture2D(text, gl_FragCoord.xy / size).xy;

  gl_FragColor = vec4(particle.x,particle.y,0.0,1.0); // R,G,B,A
}
```

Set the value of the `size` uniform by `[NUM_PARTICLES, 1]`:

```js
// Apply Texture
shaderTexture.shader(theShader); // set shader
theShader.setUniform('text', particleTexture); // send particleTexture to shader
theShader.setUniform('size', [NUM_PARTICLES, 1]);
shaderTexture.rect(0,0,NUM_PARTICLES,1); // set rect to recieve shader out
```

[image]

---

If you are using [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf) you have the option to use [`texelFetch`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/texelFetch.xhtml) to lookup the texture with integral pixel coordinates or get the size of the texture using [`textureSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/textureSize.xhtml).
Unfortunately *p5.js* ([`createCanvas()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas)) doesn't seem to provide a [WebGL 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/) context, so this is not an option.